# Javascript template literals - retrieve subcollection sets

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have data I need to integrate in a string using Template literals. I'm managining to do it except for when the data is of the type Collection.set.

My data is made of a table called **Company** with multiple records. I need to loop inside it to retrieve the data for each company( this bit is OK and already works), but then inside each company one of the attribute/column called **company_tags** is of type Collection.set So i need to loop (sort of loop inside the loop) to retrieve **the data in order to inject it inside a Template literal**, and this part I am failing to do it.

**Javascript code**

```
var html = "";
result.forEach(function(msg) {       
  console.log(msg);
  console.log(msg.company_tags);           
  msg.company_tags.forEach(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
  });

  html += `
    <tr id="company-1234" data-id="1234">
            <td class="name">              
                <h2>This is the company name ${msg.company_name}</h2> for which they agree to send an email to ${msg.company_email}
            <td class="location">              
               <h3> ${msg.company_location_city}</h3>
            </td>
            <td class="tags">              
                <h2>yhis is one of the company tags: <b>${msg.company_tags[i]} </b> and it looks nice</h2>          
            </td>
          </tr>  
        `;

      });
      document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = html;
```

Of course above the part `<h2>This are the company tags: ${msg.company_tags[i]}` does not work.

I made several attempts I show further below at reaching this Collection set but failed.

The global data called "msg" in the code above comes from a third party. To show you the structure of the data I need to parse/loop/retrieve look like here are the results of the console.log you see on the code above:

The data is the following: this is one of the Company record shown by the console.log in the code above:

**console.log(msg) outputs**

```
c {createdAt: Wed Jul 04 2018 16:49:56 GMT+0200 (CEST), updatedAt: Mon Jul 09 2018 15:26:25 GMT+0200 (CEST), _metadata: d}
company_email: "companyemail1@example.com"
company_name: "example name"  
company_location : "Dublin" 
company_tags: Set(3)
updatedAt: and so on...
d {_isLocked: false, _readyPromise: Promise, _deferred: null, _root: c, _state: 0, …}
```

**console.log(msg.company_tags) outputs** something I am not sure to fully understand. Seems like what is called  Collection set.

```
Set(3) {"tag1", "improvement", "sexy"}
size : 3
__persistedSize__ : 3
__persistedState__: 
{tag1: "tag1", improvement: "improvement", sexy: "sexy"}
__proto__ : Set
[[Entries]] : Array(3)
  > 0 : "tag1"
  > 1 : "improvement"
  > 2: "sexy"
  length : 3
```

Today when I my javascript code (see above) operates, I manage to have in my html the right data shown for the columns of "string "type. So the part below works fine for me:

```
<h2>This is the company name ${msg.company_name}</h2> for which they agree to send an email to ${msg.company_email}
```

BUT the part below with the column of type Collection.set does not work and shows "undefined"

```
<td class="tags">              
                <h2>This is one of the company tags: ${msg.company_tags[i]}            
            </td>
```

It's like I need to loop again (inside the other loopForEach).

Some attempts that failed:

```
var html = "";
result.forEach(function(msg) {   
  html += `
    <tr id="company-67851" data-id="67851">
            <td class="name">              
                <h2>This is the company name ${msg.company_name}</h2> for which they agree to send an email to ${msg.company_email}
            <td class="location">              
               <h3> ${msg.company_location_city}</h3>
            </td>
            <td class="tags">              
                <h2>This is one of the company tags:  <b>${ msg.company_tags.forEach(function(value) {                   
                        <h2>value</h2>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  });
                } </h2> and it looks nice           
            </td>
          </tr>  
        `;

      });
      document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = html;
```

I also tried

```
${ msg.company_tags.forEach( (k, v) => `<h2>${v}</h2>`).join(" ")  }
```

and also

```
${msg.company_tags.map(company_tag => <h2>This is one of the company tags: ${company_tag}</h2> and it looks nice`).join('')}
```

but I'm always getting UNDEFINED error or even sometimes 
 `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: .map is not a function`

Nothing has been working so far. It's a little over my head as a javascript rookie.

My goals is that for example I see in the html for the example of record I gave above:

```
<td class="tags">              
  <h2>This is one of the company tags: <b>tag1</b> and it looks nice</h2> 
  <h2>These are the company tags: <b>imrovement</b> and it looks nice</h2> 

  <h2>These are the company tags: <b>sexy</b> and it looks nice</h2>                        
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to convert `msg.company_tags` set into array:

```
var company_tags = []
msg.company_tags.forEach((k,v) => company_tags.push(v))
```

Then you should be able to `map` not `forEach` over it, as only `map` returns from function, `forEach` is used for side effects. 
Also you can fetch generating of company tags into separate function.

```
${company_tags.map(company_tag => `<h2>This is one of the company tags: ${company_tag}</h2> and it looks nice`).join('')}
```